# regular expression execution time jumps sharply after 100th pattern

Tags: python

I started with the first code snippet below to search a list of lines and convert all keywords (identified in a separate list) in each line to lower case. For my test list of lines about 800 lines long, the keyword substitution for the entire list of lines takes less than a second as long as my keyword list is 100 items or fewer. When I extend the list to 101 items or more, the processing time jumps to over 9 seconds.

Using the second snippet (where all the patterns for the keyword list are compiled) drops the total processing time back down below 1 second.

Does anyone know why the processing time for the non-compiled substitution search is so sensitive to the number of items searched per input line? I'm surprised it jumps so sharply after 100 keywords.

snippet #1

```
for line in lines_in:
    for keyword in keywords:
        rawstring = r'\b' + keyword + r'\b'
        line = re.sub(rawstring, keyword, line, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

snippet #2

```
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    re_pattern = re.compile(r'\b' + keywords[i] + r'\b', re.IGNORECASE)
    pattern.append(re_pattern)

for line in lines_in:
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        line = pattern[i].sub(keywords[i], line, 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Python caches the compiled regex internally, and the size of that internal cache is 100 (as can be seen [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/re.py?view=markup) on line 227. Furthermore, you can see on line 246-247 that when the cache get's over the max size it is **cleared** rather than using a more advanced cache invalidation algorithm. This is essentially means that each iteration of your loop is blowing out the cache and causing all 100+ regexes to be recompiled.

The performance is back to "normal" in your second example because it doesn't rely on the internal cache staying intact to keep compiled regexes around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reason. It's always nice to see things work like they're designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the internal caching of compiled regular expressions within the re module.  If you are using a lot of regexp's in your code, pre-compile them rather than using re.match or re.search directly and it'll be even faster.

The internal re cache is for convenient speed in the common simple use case, not high performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for re.compile says:

> Note The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to
>   re.match(), re.search() or re.compile() are cached, so programs that
>   use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about
>   compiling regular expressions.

I think we now know the size of that cache.

Comment: @grncdr, thanks for pointing out the reason. It's always good to see things work like they're designed to.